# Propagate include/library directories and linker params to all projects within a solution?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

I have several projects within a single "Solution," in Visual Studio 2010.  All of these projects use the same linker options, directories, and so on.  These settings are stored in the properties of each project independently, which means I have to go into each and set them for every build type (debug/release/etc).

Is there anyway to have these settings in a single place, so that all projects within the solution use my directories and linker options by default?  The language is C++ if that's a factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [Property Sheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4xbdz1e.aspx), place the common configuration properties in the Property Sheet, and have all of your projects inherit from the Property Sheet.